# SwiftUI: Unable to update the toggle component

Tags: swiftui

I have a state the decides if we need to do round up or down or nothing:

```
enum RoundingType: Codable {
  case up
  case down
}

struct ViewState {
  var roundingType: RoundingType? = nil
}
```

Then in the toggle I simply update this flag:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var state: ViewState

  func toggleRoundingType(_ roundingType: RoundingType) {
    let oldRoundingType = state.roundingType
    // if same rounding type, cancel it
    // Otherwise, set it
    let isCancel = oldRoundingType == roundingType
    if isCancel {
      state.roundingType = nil
    } else {
      state.roundingType = roundingType
    }
  }
}
```

This is my View:

```
struct HomeView: View {
  
  @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
  var body: some View {
    let state = viewModel.state

      HStack {
        Spacer()

        SUITextToggle(label: loc(.roundUp), isOn: state.roundingType == .up) { _ in
          viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.up)
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        SUITextToggle(label: loc(.roundDown), isOn: state.roundingType == .down) { _ in
          viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.down)
        }
        
        Spacer()
      }
    }
  }
```

This view renders 2 toggles, and user can turn on/off the round up/down toggles.

This is my toggle implementation:

```
public struct SUITextToggle: View {
  
  @State var isOn: Bool
  private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool> {
      return isOn
    } set: { newValue in
      isOn = newValue
      onChange(newValue)
    }
  }
  
  let label: String
  let onChange: (Bool) -> Void
  
  init(label: String, isOn: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.label = label
    self.isOn = isOn
    self.onChange = onChange
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Toggle(label, isOn: binding)
      .toggleStyle(.button)
  }
}
```

Now I have an issue that when I turn on "Up", then turn on "Down", the "Up" button is not automatically turned off. For some reason the "Up" button is not refreshed.

[image]

EDIT:

minimal reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct SUITextToggle: View {
  
  @State var isOn: Bool
  private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool> {
      return isOn
    } set: { newValue in
      isOn = newValue
      onChange(newValue)
    }
  }
  
  let label: String
  let onChange: (Bool) -> Void
  
  init(label: String, isOn: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.label = label
    self.isOn = isOn
    self.onChange = onChange
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Toggle(label, isOn: binding)
      .toggleStyle(.button)
  }
}

struct HomeView: View {
  @State var isOn: Bool = true
  var body: some View {
    // Only one of these 2 toggles should be on

    SUITextToggle(label: "Toggle 1", isOn: isOn) { _ in
      isOn = !isOn
    }
    SUITextToggle(label: "Toggle 2", isOn: !isOn) { _ in
      isOn = !isOn
    }
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView())
    present(hostingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I think i have pasted all the code here if im not mistaken

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, but I think the issue is that there is no forward communication with the toggle other than the `init` so it never gets notified that it should be re-rendered

Comment: @loremipsum added the Minimal Reproducible Example at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no two-way communication that is compatible with SwiftUI. You communicate one-way on `init` and then use the completion handler. That does not tell the other toggle to re-render.

I made some changes to make it more SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI
enum RoundingType: String, Codable, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible, Identifiable {
    case up
    case down
    //Set the description here
    var description: String{
        "round\(rawValue)"
    }
    //Make the enum Identifiable
    var id: String{
        rawValue
    }
}
//No changes
struct ViewState {
    var roundingType: RoundingType? = nil
}
@MainActor
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //Set a default value. Missing from code
    @Published var state: ViewState = .init(roundingType: .up)
    //Remove func
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct ToggleHomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            //Iterate through all the options and provide a toggle for each option
            ForEach(RoundingType.allCases){ type in
                SUITextToggle(selectedType: $viewModel.state.roundingType, toggleType: type, label: type.description)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct ToggleHomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToggleHomeView()
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
public struct SUITextToggle: View {
    //Bindng is a two-way connection
    @Binding var selectedType: RoundingType?
    ///type that toggle represents
    let toggleType: RoundingType
    ///proxy that uses the selectedType and toggleType to set toggle to on/off if the two variables are the same
    private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool> {
            return selectedType == toggleType
        } set: { newValue in
            if newValue{
                selectedType = toggleType
            }else{
                //if you remove the nil set a default value here
                selectedType = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    let label: String
    public var body: some View {
        Toggle(label, isOn: binding)
            .toggleStyle(.button)
    }
}
```

But you can preserve most of your code if you remove the `@State`. This wrapper is meant to preserve its value through `body`'s re-rendering.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
public struct SUITextToggle: View {
    
    var isOn: Bool
    private var binding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool> {
            return isOn
        } set: { newValue in
            onChange(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    let label: String
    let onChange: (Bool) -> Void
    
    init(label: String, isOn: Bool, onChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.label = label
        self.isOn = isOn
        self.onChange = onChange
    }
    public var body: some View {
        Toggle(label, isOn: binding)
            .toggleStyle(.button)
    }
}
```

Another "hack" that is out there is to force `View`s to recreate by setting the `id` but this causes unnecessary rendering. Efficiency issues as your app grows will become noticeable

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct ToggleHomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        let state = viewModel.state
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            SUITextToggle(label: "roundUp", isOn: state.roundingType == .up) { _ in
                viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.up)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            SUITextToggle(label: "roundDown", isOn: state.roundingType == .down) { _ in
                viewModel.toggleRoundingType(.down)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }.id(state.roundingType)
    }
}
```

Comment: in my original code, why doesn't it tell the other toggle to re-render? I passed in the property inside a published state there.

Comment: @John `SUITextToggle` would have to be completely recreated because you only pass forward the value on `init`.  Watch the Demystifying SwiftUI video from WWDC 21 they go over how SwiftUI optimizes rendering based on what the wrappers are telling it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - i watched that video and I think I should have good understanding of how it works. But this still puzzles me a bit. I've seen many other cases when we pass in a @State value in a view's constructor (e.g. a Text), and in those cases, the view gets updated successfully.

Comment: @John `@State` and `@StateObject` are meant to preserve their value with renders and as I typed this I realized you can just remove the `@State` and your code will work, I updated the answer to include this, this will force the `body` to recreate.

Comment: Will it be a problem if the `isOn` variable is not updated in the `set` closure?

Comment: Interestingly it worked, but I feel a bit iffy with not updating `isOn` ivar.

Comment: You will re-create everything the `init` gets called again, it works, give the code I added a try. I also added another "hack" that is out there that would cause the `init` to get called again, setting the `id`

Comment: Yeah, it isn't ideal but those are the SwiftUI "rules".

Comment: I will accept this answer because it worked. But I still feel a bit confused. Especially after you said that removing @State also works. Let me digest a bit

Comment: No problem, just tag me or comment here if you have any other questions, I'll be on tomorrow at some point.